# Evaluate the limit of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$\lim_{y\to0} \int_{0}^{2} \frac{e^{(x+y)^2}-e^{x^2}}{y} dx$$

let $y_n\to 0$

define $f_n(x)=\frac{e^{(x+y_n)^2}-e^{x^2}}{y_n}$
it seems that we can use mean value theorem for $e^{x^2}$, and use DCT. Is my thought correct?

Comment: Wait a minute... should the $e^{x^2}$ be in the exponent? is it supposed to be
$$e^{(x+y)^2-e^{x^2}}$$
or
$$e^{(x+y)^2}-e^{x^2}$$?

Comment: Thank you, you are right

Comment: Other than that, your approach seems ok to me!

Comment: That's definitely the correct approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x) = e^{x^2}$ then the mean value theorem tell us

$$ g(y) = \frac{e^{(x+y)^2} - e^{x^2}}{y} = \frac{e^{(x+y)^2} - e^{x^2}}{(x+y) -x } = f_{y}'(c) $$ where the notation implies that for different values of $y$, you get different values of $f'$.  But for $x \in [0,2]$ we have that

$f_{y}'(c) = g(y) < \max_{y \in [0,2]}\{f'(y)\} =  f'(2)$ so we may apply DCT and get

$$ \lim_{y \to 0}\int_{0}^{2} \frac{e^{(x+y)^2} - e^{x^2}}{y} dx = \int_{0}^{2} \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{e^{(x+y)^2} - e^{x^2}}{y} dx = \int_{0}^{2} 2xe^{x^2} dx $$

Answer (score 4):

We don't need to invoke the mean value theorem, or the Dominated Convergence Theorem, or both to evaluate the coveted limit.

Rather we simply write the term of interest as

$$\int_0^2 \frac{e^{(x+y)^2}-e^{x^2}}{y}\,dx=\frac{\int_y^{y+2} e^{x^2}\,dx-\int_0^2 e^{x^2}\,dx }{y}$$

Then, applying the definition of the derivative of $f(y)=\int_y^{y+2}e^{x^2}\,dx$ at $y=0$ immediately gives

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\int_0^2 \frac{e^{(x+y)^2}-e^{x^2}}{y}\,dx=\lim_{y\to 0}\left(e^{(y+2)^2}-e^{y^2}\right)=e^4-1$$

And we are done!

Comment: This is definitely the correct approach in my opinion. But of course, it is good to know the powerful theorems of integration...

Comment: @mickep I agree that the MVT and DCT are indeed requisite tools for analysis.  But one should use the tools appropriate for the task and not rely on unnecessary tools, especially when the more elementary ones not only suffice but are more efficient.  ;-))